# Copy & Paste photos between albums

Tags: ios, photos.app

Is there a way to copy an entire photo (not just a shortcut to the photo) from your camera role to another photo album?  Now that we can edit photots on the iPhone I thought it might be useful to make a copy of a photo before messing with it.

After selecting a photo and hitting "copy", there doesn't appear to be a way to paste it into another album.  Selecting the "add to" option, and adding it to another album does appear to work; however, editing the photo in one album affects both the original photo, and the "copy" of it.

Is there any way to make a copy of the actual photo, and paste it in another album?

Answer (score 2):

As you are asking for *any way*:

- select photo you wish to duplicate
- Press "Share" and "Email Photo"
- Send email to yourself using actual size of picture
- Once email is back select picture and save to Photo Roll

PS: I tried to just cancel the email first and keeping a copy in Drafts. But it seems you can't select a picture out of a mail in the Drafts folder.

Comment: +1 for the workaround.  Is there really no native way to do this?  Seems like a pretty big oversight on Apple's part.

Comment: Well, the limited editor built into the Photos app is nondestructive anyway (try cropping an image and trying again the next day!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly fond of this answer but it does work... you can purchase the Pastebot application (all their apps are fantastic) and copy the image in the native Photo app.  Next open Pastebot and you should see your image pop into the display.  Select the image preview which will open the full image.  At the bottom, click save image and you'll now have two copies of the image.

Just had the same issue as you and this was the workaround I used (I had already purchased Pastebot).

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to find answers to the same question and I guess I will settle for the email workaround. A screenshot won't work since I want to save a full-resolution copy. I do like that edits are reversible, but sometimes I'd like to save, in my camera roll, both the original and the edited version.

Comment: Hi, and welcome. Your post is welcome, but I would suggest to make it a comment, since it does not really add a new answer to the original question. You can also research a bit, find a new solution, and post it here. Have fun!

Comment: @myhd As a new user, commenting is disabled and not an option for this user. Also, since it bridged Patrick and longda's answers and also explains why someone would ask what the OP asked, I think it's a fine answer to keep here as it moves the discussion forward a bit in my eyes.

Comment: @bmike You are right! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This works for copy and Paste. **BUT THIS WILL STILL EDIT ALL VERSIONS.**

But before you do any of this make sure there is at least one image already in the copy to Album.  If the Album is empty you will never see the paste contextual menu.

1, Go to an Album.  Press the **Select** button and select the image.

2,Press the share button.

3, choose the 'Copy' button.

4, Go to you other Album.

5, hold your thing down on the Album page until the **Paste** contextual menu appears.

6, Now paste the image.

---

The interesting thing is if you have iPhoto you can use the Share button and open in another app. This includes Camera Roll. Which then adds a real copy to the Camera Roll.

Answer (score -1):

Screen shot the picture.......